# How do I get argument of request to know which page is getting loaded in layout.html in web2py

Tags: layout, request, web2py

I wanted to change the layout design depending on the page.
So can I get the value which will basically give information about the page getting loaded.
Like

```
{{is_mobile=request.user_agent().is_mobile}}
```

I want to use

```
{{if request.page =='page1'}}
```

in layout.html in web2py

Answer (score 0):

The controller name is in `request.controller`, and the function name is in `request.function` (you will need both of those to uniquely identify a particular "page"). You could also use `response.view`, which will generally include the controller and function (e.g., "default/index.html").